# Change the order of characters in a word

Tags: php, words, strpos, suffix

I have the following nomenclature:

```
0100455_LM_Izaguirre
```

I need to change to be as follows:

```
LM_0100455
```

The idea would be to first put the suffix "LM", then the code "0100455" and erase everything else. The problem is that the suffix is not unique, it can vary "LM, LI, AQ"

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: Try searching explode and array index :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = '0100455_LM_Izaguirre';
$data = explode("_", $str);

// where:
// $data[0] = 0100455;
// $data[1] = LM;
// $data[2] = Izaguirre;


$str = $data[1].'_'.$data[0];

echo $str;
```

// Output : LM_0100455

Answer (score 1):

Try to something like this...

```
$string = '0100455_LM_Izaguirre';
$String1 = explode('_', $string);
echo $String1['1']."_".$String1['0'];
```